# MSSQL stored procedure call from ADO - not running properly

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ado

I have sp in MSSQL server - code below. When I run it from job, or SSMS it runs OK. But I need to run it from VB6 app with ADODB.

My VB6 code:

```
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = CNN
cmd.CommandTimeout = 180
cmd.CommandText = "dbbackup"
cmd.CommandType = ADODB.CommandTypeEnum.adCmdStoredProc
cmd.Execute(, , ADODB.ConnectOptionEnum.adAsyncConnect)
```

Problem is: When database backup is almost done - about 90+%, cmd.State changes from Executing to Closed and VB6 code continue in executing (to this moment it waits for sp to complete). But there is a lot of code after backup which never run this way(old backup delete,...). I realized that “Last database backup” property on MSSQL database was not set and in table msdb.dbo.backupset there are no rows for my backup. But there si good restorable backup on HDD.

When i stops program for 5 minutes in debug, sp runs properly to end and everything is OK. This backup code is last code in app run and after it ends program closes all connections and exits. I added wait to VB6 code and it helps on some servers, but many other servers still has same problem.

I think main question is why MSSQL server returns control flow to VB6 code and sp is not completed yet.

Thanks

sp code:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[dbBackup]
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
RECONFIGURE

If OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DBName','u') IS NULL
    Create Table #DBName
        (
        ID              int identity (1,1) ,
        Name            varchar(128) not null ,
        RetentionPeriod int null,
        BackupPath      varchar(255) default(''),
        DBSize          float default(0)
        )

If OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ExistingBackups', 'u') IS NULL
    Create Table #ExistingBackups
        (
        Name varchar(128) ,
        ID int identity (1,1)
        )

Declare @Path varchar(255)
Declare @sql varchar(1000)
Declare @Name varchar(128)
Declare @RetentionPeriod int
Declare @LastBackupToKeep varchar(8)
Declare @ID int
Declare @MaxID int
Declare @eName varchar(255)
Declare @eMaxID int
Declare @eID int
Declare @eTimeStamp varchar(20)
Declare @errMsg nvarchar(2048)
Declare @errCount int; set @errCount = 0;
Declare @freeSpace bigint
Declare @pageSize float
Declare @dbSize bigint
Declare @procDate datetime
Declare @Sklad char(3)
Declare @backupName as varchar(255)

Select @pageSize = v.low / 1024 From master..spt_values v (noLock) Where v.number = 1 And v.[type] = 'E'
Select Top 1 @sklad = sklad_id From dbo.pohyb (noLock) Where Convert(int, sklad_id) > 500
Set @procDate = GETDATE()

Truncate Table #DBName

Insert Into #DBName (Name, RetentionPeriod, BackupPath)
Select  DBName, BackupsToStore, BackupPath
From    dbo.databaseBackup (noLock)
Where   runBackup = 1

Select @MaxID = max(ID), @ID = 0 From #DBName

While @ID < @MaxID
Begin
    Select @ID = min(ID) From #DBName Where ID > @ID

    Select @Name = Name, @RetentionPeriod = RetentionPeriod, @Path = BackupPath
    From #DBName
    Where ID = @ID

    If SUBSTRING(@Path, Len(@Path), 1) <> '\' Set @Path = @Path + '\'

    Set @sql = 'Update #DBName Set DBSize= (Select Round(Sum(size) *' + CONVERT(varchar, @pageSize) + '/1024, 0) From ' + @Name + '.dbo.sysfiles (noLock)) Where Name = ''' + @Name + ''''

    Exec (@sql)

    Select @dbSize = DBSize From #DBName

    --Exec @freeSpace = dbo.getDiskFreeSpace @drive = @Path

    --If @freeSpace > @dbSize
        --Begin
            Set @eTimeStamp = REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, @procDate, 113), ' ', '_'), ':', '-')
            Set @sql = @Path + @Name + '_' + @eTimeStamp + '.bak'
            Set @errMsg = 'OK'
            Begin Try

                SET @backupName = 'Objednavky backup by job ' + CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 104) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 108);

                Backup Database @Name To Disk = @sql 
                    WITH NAME = @backupName;

                -------mazanie backupu begin
                Truncate Table #ExistingBackups
                Set @sql = 'dir /B /OD ' + @Path + @Name + '_*.bak'

                Insert #ExistingBackups Exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql

                If Exists (Select 1 From #ExistingBackups Where PATINDEX('%File Not Found%', Name) > 0)
                    Truncate Table #ExistingBackups

                Delete From #ExistingBackups Where Name IS NULL

                Select @eID = 0

                Select @eMaxID = Max(ID) - @RetentionPeriod From #ExistingBackups

                While @eID < @eMaxID
                Begin
                    Select @eID = Min(ID) From #ExistingBackups Where ID > @eID
                    Select @eName = Name From #ExistingBackups Where ID = @eID

                    Set @sql = 'del ' + @Path + @eName
                    Exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
                End

                Truncate Table #ExistingBackups
                -------mazanie backupu end

            End Try
            Begin Catch
                Set @errMsg = @errMsg + '||' + CONVERT(varchar,ERROR_MESSAGE())
                Set @errCount = @errCount + 1;
            End Catch
        --End
    --Else
        --Set @errMsg = 'Pln? disk (Vo?n? miesto: ' + CONVERT(varchar, @freeSpace) + ' MB, potrebn? aspo?: ' + CONVERT(varchar, @dbSize) + ' MB)'

    Insert Into [dbo].[databaseBackup_log] ([Sklad_id], [DBName], [BackupDate], [Status]) Values (@Sklad, @Name, @procDate, Ltrim(Rtrim(CONVERT(varchar,@errMsg))))
End

Drop Table #DBName
Drop Table #ExistingBackups

IF @errCount > 0 BEGIN
    RAISERROR (@errMsg, 16, 2) WITH SETERROR
END

RETURN 0;

END
```

Comment: Jobs and SSMS don't have a `CommandTimeout`, which the ADO code does. How long does the backup take to run?

Comment: it depends on concrete database - from 1 minute to 2 hours

Comment: But your command will timeout after 3 minutes. If you need it to wait for however long it takes, set the `CommandTimeout` to 0.